# Objective-C: Photo Viewer for iOS with ARC support?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, automatic-ref-counting

The last couple of days I've tried to implement a Photo Viewer in my iOS 5.0 Application in Xcode 4.2. By project is running with Automatic Reference Counting (ARC). I've tried [Three20 Photo Viewer](https://github.com/facebook/three20) but this has a lot of dependencies and is really a heavy piece to include in my project. Next I've tried [EGOPhotoViewer](https://github.com/enormego/PhotoViewer) which really seems as a great solution for my purpose -- but sadly I does not support ARC and because of that, I cannot compile it inside my project.

Does anybody know a Photo Viewer for iOS which supports ARC -- or could, in some way, be added as a library to a project running with ARC?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is possible to disable ARC for individual files by adding the -fno-objc-arc to a file.

To disable ARC for a file select your project in Xcode 4, go to the *build phases* tab, select the files you want to disable for ARC, add the *-fno-objc-arc* compiler flag to these files.

Answer (score 15):

You might want to take a look at [MWPhotoBrowser](http://github.com/mwaterfall/mwphotobrowser) - you can add it to your project as a static library which will work independantly of your project's ARC settings.

MWPhotoBrowser can display one or more images by providing either UIImage objects, or URLs to files, web images or library assets. The photo browser handles the downloading and caching of photos from the web seamlessly. Photos can be zoomed and panned, and optional (customisable) captions can be displayed. The browser can also be used to allow the user to select one or more photos using either the grid or main image view.

[image: MWPhotoBrowser Screenshots]

Comment: It looks very useful. Currently I'm using EGOPhotoViewer for my project. Do you know the advantages of your browser compared with EGOPhotoViewer?

Comment: One thing; you should make it more easy to add support for multiple languages.

Comment: Thanks! I've only had a quick look at EGOPhotoViewer but I think they're pretty similar. I've tried to make mine very clean, easy to use and optimised; have a play if you get the time! Thanks for the suggestion of multiple languages. There's only a few strings that would be affected so it shouldn't be difficult. I'll look into it!

Comment: This component is good indeed but for high resolution images it is giving memory warning and crashing app in ios 5 sometimes

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it:

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
  self.startX = scrollView.contentOffset.x;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
{
  //NSLog(@"scrollViewDidEndDragging");
  self.endX = scrollView.contentOffset.x;

  self.photoIdx = (int)self.startX / Normalize(1160);

  if (decelerate == FALSE)
  {
    int intoThePhoto = (int)self.photoScrollView.contentOffset.x % Normalize(1160);

    if (intoThePhoto < Normalize(1060/2))
      [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(Normalize(1160)*self.photoIdx,0) animated:YES];
    else
      [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(Normalize(1160)*(self.photoIdx+1),0) animated:YES];

  }

}

-(void)scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{

  if ((self.endX - self.startX) > 0 && self.photoIdx < ([self.photos count] -1))
    [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(Normalize(1160)*(self.photoIdx+1),0) animated:YES];
  else if ((self.endX - self.startX) < 0 && self.photoIdx != 0)
    [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(Normalize(1160)*(self.photoIdx-1),0) animated:YES];
}
```